# Unresolved external when building C++ Template Class

Tags: c++, qt4

I am trying to build a BehaviourTree data structure. The "main" class is "BTNode", and leaves (actions, commands or conditions) are "BTLeaf". Because I want a BTLeaf to perform some action  on my entities, I made it a template class which takes in an object and a member function pointer.

btnode.h:

```
#ifndef BTNODE_H
#define BTNODE_H

#include <QLinkedList>

class BTNode
{
public:
    BTNode();
    BTNode(QLinkedList<BTNode *> &children);

    ~BTNode();

    virtual bool execute() = 0;

protected:
    QLinkedList<BTNode*> _children;
};

#endif // BTNODE_H
```

btleaf.h:

```
#ifndef BTLEAF_H
#define BTLEAF_H

#include "btnode.h"

template <class T> class BTLeaf : public BTNode
{
public:
    BTLeaf(T* object, bool(T::*fpt)(void))
    { _object = object; _fpt=fpt; }

    /* Does not work either:
    BTLeaf(T* object, bool(T::*fpt)(void))
        : BTNode()
    { _object = object; _fpt=fpt; }
    */

    virtual bool execute()
    { return (_object->*_fpt)(); }

private:
    bool (T::*_fpt)(); //member function pointer
    T* _object;
};
#endif // BTLEAF_H
```

When I try to build the solution (using Qt Creator), I get:

```
spider.obj:-1: error: LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall BTNode::BTNode(void)" (??0BTNode@@QAE@XZ) referenced in function "public: __thiscall BTLeaf<class Spider>::BTLeaf<class Spider>(class Spider *,bool (__thiscall Spider::*)(void))"
```

you can see my attempted solution commented out in my code. If I remove the `public BTNode` part and use my btleaf "manually", I get the desired result. Any ideas?

**Edit:**
It might be worth nothing that I create a BTLeaf in my `Spider` class this way (temporarely, for testing purposes):

```
BTLeaf<Spider> test(this, &Spider::sayHello);
test.execute();
```

Comment: Are you defining `BTNode::BTNode()`? It doesn't look like it. `BTLeaf::BTLeaf(T* object, bool(T::*fpt)(void))` needs `BTNode::BTNode()`, but it doesn't look like you're actually defining an implementation for `BTNode::BTNode()`.

Comment: Didn't know the problem was this simple. I didn't want BTNode::BTNode() to do anything particular (except having an empty children list), so I didn't know I had to implement it. Thanks a lot Cornstalks!

Comment: If you don't need it, don't define it. If it's not doing anything you can just remove the `BTNode();` declaration.

Comment: That was my first attempt, but if I do that,  I get `'BTNode' : no appropriate default constructor available` for the following code: `BTLeaf(T* object, bool(T::*fpt)(void))
    { _object = object; _fpt=fpt; }`

Comment: Oh I see, sorry. That's because of `BTNode(QLinkedList<BTNode *> &children);`. Having that constructor prevents a default constructor being made for you, and so you do need `BTNode();`. I overlooked you had another constructor defined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Presumably that BTNode default (no-argument) constructor you have declared is not defined anywhere (at least, not anywhere that your linker sees).

Comment: That's exactly right! For anyone tha might have the same situation arise, please see Cornstalks' comment on my original question for further details. Thanks!